# Time synch in AD

Tags: active-directory, time-synchronization

Is it possible to force exactly same time to all clients in AD? If yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the Windows Time Service runnning on your PDC.

It's best practise to sync with an external NTP server. 
This link should give you all the info you need:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773013(WS.10).aspx

Comment: -1. Does NOT answer the question. Windows time services are not "exact" but good enough for Kerberos, ONLY. The ONLY eact way is a third party program. Exact defines as keeping things within milliseconds, not seconds. AD time sync varies up to I think half a minute or so.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using NET TIME command in logon script, as per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314090